# Is POSIX wrong about crontab with non-asterisk month and day-of-week?

Tags: cron, posix

#### Background

It is widely known that the UNIX cron runs jobs when *either* day-of-month *or* day-of-week matches, if both are specified with explicit values rather than an asterisk wildcard:

```
0 0 * * 1     # every Monday
0 0 1 * *     # every month's first day
0 0 1 * 1     # every Monday *and also* every month's first day
0 0 1 * 1-7   # every day
0 0 1-31 * 1  # every day
```

Note how these commonly seen examples all have `*` in the month field.

#### POSIX on non-asterisk month

[The POSIX specification actually says this for `crontab`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html) (emphasis mine):

> The specification of days can be made by two fields (day of the month and day of the week). If month, day of month, and day of week are all <asterisk> characters, every day shall be matched. If either the month or day of month is specified as an element or list, but the day of week is an <asterisk>, the month and day of month fields shall specify the days that match. If ***both month and*** day of month are specified as an <asterisk>, but day of week is an element or list, then only the specified days of the week match. Finally, if ***either the month or*** day of month is specified as an element or list, and the day of week is also specified as an element or list, then any day matching ***either the month and day of month, or the day of week,*** shall be matched.

This seems to declare that the following schedules will match ***either** month **or** day-of-week:*

```
0 0 * 1 1     # every month's every Monday *and also* every day in January
0 0 * 1-12 1  # every day
0 0 1 1 1     # every month's every Monday *and also* 1 January
```

#### Non-asterisk month in practice

As far as I can tell, no common modern or historical cron implementation actually does this, including [SVR4 cron](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=SysVR4/cmd/cron/cron.c) (which must have been [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345753/865331) to match day-of-month *or* day-of-week) and its descendants in [OpenSolaris](https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris/blob/4a302de4ba97ac29f95ee810f6c5a494172f38ca/usr/src/cmd/cron/cron.c) and [illumos](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/6cb54de2051534cc59e36ddc42abe1960e47c133/usr/src/cmd/cron/cron.c) as well as [Vixie cron](https://github.com/svagner/vixie-cron/blob/13d13f0b38d73e7a415caa77b5821be92dd16f70/cron.c#L359-L362) and its descendants [Cronie](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/blob/8191b84648efc4dd583fbbfc4350a9cc9bfd58fb/src/cron.c#L574-L578) and [FreeBSD](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/1c6adcd7ae2efec7872cb5bf1c1eec75b3aa8e95/usr.sbin/cron/cron/cron.c#L331-L335), [OpenBSD](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/f7df26a3b085668ba00a62d15d953846f643aaa4/usr.sbin/cron/cron.c#L309-L312), [NetBSD](https://github.com/NetBSD/src/blob/a18f5514bb434767da2a9d70903a87977c352e01/external/bsd/cron/dist/cron.c#L409-L413), [DragonFly BSD](https://github.com/DragonFlyBSD/DragonFlyBSD/blob/4f048b1cbc45fb4943dcb654296991d5f5dbca7d/usr.sbin/cron/cron/cron.c#L255-L259) and [macOS](https://github.com/apple-opensource/cron/blob/a8285ef57afa6af991469b3c9c031623ee9f7b01/cron/cron.c#L304-L307) crons, as well as [BusyBox crond](https://github.com/nawawi/busybox/blob/a949399d178f7b052ada2099c62621736eafce44/miscutils/crond.c#L335-L359).

Instead, all of these implementations always require a match of the month field regardless of what form any field takes, and only change their day-of-month matching logic based on whether the two day-of-month and day-of-week fields contain `*` or explicit value lists:

```
0 0 * 1 1     # every Monday in January
0 0 * 1-12 1  # every Monday
0 0 1 1 1     # every Monday in January *and also* 1 January
```

(or in the case of BusyBox, based on whether the fields contain full value ranges or strict subsets, regardless of the syntax used)

#### Specification bug?

Is the behaviour described in the POSIX specification actually implemented anywhere? Is the description a bug in the specification that might be corrected if a defect report is submitted? Is there a story behind why it is currently phrased this way?

Comment: No I don't think this is implemented anywhere, and I think the standard implementation is reasonable, ( `0 0 1 * 1` means every 1st day of month or week) while the last sentence of the quoted text is strange. I don't know where and if I could see the revisions of these docs, or if any word could be there by mistake. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357126/why-crontab-uses-or-when-both-day-of-month-and-day-of-week-specified) is interesting, with a link to a good cron code comment.

Comment: I agree that it sounds like a defect in POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

*Digital Unix* v4 (aka *OSF1*) implemented this (archived [man page here](http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/MAN/MAN1/0142____.HTM)):

> You can specify the days on which the command is to execute in two fields
> (day of the month and day of the week).  You can specify both fields, or
> you can specify only one field.  To use only one field to specify the days,
> the other field should contain an asterisk (*).  If both methods are used,
> the command is executed whenever either of the specifications is met.

And so does *Solaris* proper, though the [text of the man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/crontab-1.html) lacks clarity (and has done since forever), Example 3 is clear on the intended behaviour:

> Example 3 Specifying Days of the Month and Week
>
> This example runs a command on the first and fifteenth of each month, as well as on every Monday:
>
> 0 0 1,15 * 1

[Dillon `crond`](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html) interprets `* * 2 * mon` to mean "the 2nd Monday of the month", which while useful, is also non-standard.
The answers in the [question linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357126/why-crontab-uses-or-when-both-day-of-month-and-day-of-week-specified) by @thanasisp are useful to read at this point. The "or" behaviour is from *System V R2* (ca. 1985) at least.

I have found that when reading the Open Group documentation one needs to be aware of

- pedantic meaning of certain words in certain contexts, just like RFCs, but more so
- sections of text bounded by ⌦ ... ⌫ symbols (an unusual convention as these symbols are forward- and backward-delete)

There is text within the crontab reference marked `[UP] ⌦ ... ⌫` which indicates optional behaviour (for `crontab -e`) on the part of **User** **P**ortable Utilies, the "Input Files" section does not have any such marks.

> Finally, if either the month or day of month is specified as an element or list, and the day of week is also specified as an element or list, then any day matching either the month and day of month, or the day of week, **shall** be matched.

I have highlighted the word "shall", which [leaves no doubt](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap01.html#tag_01_07_01):

> shall
>
> For an implementation that conforms to POSIX.1-2017, describes a feature or behavior that is mandatory. An application can rely on the existence of the feature or behavior.
>
> For an application or user, describes a behavior that is mandatory.

But, as a system administrator I would tend to consider the specification abstract, it cannot be wrong (unless it is so wrong it cannot be implemented). The fault, if any, is within an implementation if it does not conform to a claimed specification (possibly with the help of `POSIXLY_CORRECT` which is the usual get-out-of-jail-free for implementors who bend the specification in the interest of sanity or user expectations).

Comment: You seem to be describing the behaviour when month is `*`, day-of-week is not `*` and day-of-month is not `*`. This is already assumed by the question; see the “Background” section. The problematic part is when _month is **not** `*`._